# node lodash shuffle method does not seem to shuffle in this example

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm trying to randomize an array of dates using lodash shuffle but it doesnt seem to be working.

```js
import shuffle from "lodash";
async function runDates() {
    let searchList = [];
    for (let d = new Date('12/01/2022'); d <= new Date('12/31/2022'); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        searchList.push([d.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{month:'2-digit',day:'2-digit',year:'numeric'})]);    }
    searchList=shuffle(searchList);
    console.log(searchList);
}
runDates();
```

Comment: Change `import shuffle from "lodash";` to `import { shuffle } from "lodash";`

Comment: Hmm, I get an error: SyntaxError: Named export 'shuffle' not found. The requested module 'lodash' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.  CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using: import pkg from 'lodash'; const { shuffle } = pkg;   AND what's the difference between using the curly brackets and not?